# Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express window numbers and debugging crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Installed Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express from the ISO available from this page:

[http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/](https://web.archive.org/web/20110612193544/http://www.microsoft.com:80/express/Downloads/)

If it helps this is the info from the about visual studio window:

---

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2010: Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
- Microsoft .NET Framework - Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel
- Installed Version: WD Express

---

For some reason I get silly big red numbers appearing in the right hand side and on tool bar windows. Whenever I resize the window the numbers change and they are extremely annoying.

Have been through all the settings and options and cannot find the 'Turn off the silly big red numbers everywhere' check box. Can anyone show me where this is please?

[image: vs2010 window numbers]
<sub>(source: [solutionrevolution.net](http://www.solutionrevolution.net/stackoverflow/vs2010-window-numbers.png))</sub>

More annoying than silly big red numbers is debugging against IIS7 where visual studio just hangs and nothing will work again until a restart. Vista Business running 32 bit. VS2008 works fine on the same machine.

If anyone has any pointers or help for me it would be very much appreciated

Comment: Are you **sure** that isn't some other application putting those in?

Comment: Have tried re-installing and installing again, resetting layout, resetting settings. everything. 

Cannot think of what other application could be adding this in. 

It's Web Developer Express so no plug ins work so it's not re sharper or anything like that. I am at a loss.

Comment: Is this the only application affected?

Comment: I have *never* seen anything like that before in VS.  Are you absolutely sure some other application isn't putting those in? (And by other application, I don't mean extension, I mean separately-installed windows application)

Comment: Somebody is playing a practical joke with you.  Or with me.

Comment: I can't think of anything else that would do that. installed it from the official microsoft site. It's stopping me from upgrading our development environment from 2008 to 2010 so I really need to fix the silly numbers and the debugging crashing issue. 

Perhaps I just need to wait for sp1 or something. sigh

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you registered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely looks like Fraps. VS2010 is written in WPF, and WPF uses DirectX to render everything, that is why Fraps putting its FPS meter on VS2010 window. Just disable Fraps.

Comment: ooh this sounds promising. Don't think I have an application called fraps installed but I'll see what I can find.....

Comment: thank you very much! My machine has a system tray tool called ATI tray tools and after some digging around I found the following page which allowed me to turn the FPS off

http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=446829

I can look at why debugging against IIS crashes next but that should be a lot easier. Thanks again